# The purpose of auxiliary lens in microscope

Tags: microscopy

Can someone explain me the purpose of auxiliary lens in microscope.

The specification says:

```
Eyepiece: Extra wide field 10x  Eyepiece w Spectacle Correction 30mm Ocular
Objective 0.7-45x , Auxiliary 2x
```

And the manufacturer claims that it is having magnification of 90X. Is it true ?

Perhaps they are multiplying the power of Objective, Eyepiece and Auxiliary to get 90X. But is correct to say the magnification is 90 X

BTW this is the [microscope](http://www.ebay.in/itm/7-90x-Zoom-Stereo-Industrial-Biology-Digital-Microscope-w-1-3Mp-USB-Camera-/161265313969?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item258c2968b1) I am talking about  and the specification is given at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be a standard Barlow Lens (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow_lens) which, when attached to one of the normal eyepieces, decreases the focal length by half and thus increases the magnification by 2X.  The previous answer describes a more complicated type of Barlow lens that turns any eyepiece into a zoom lens, which you may or may not have.

Answer (score 1):

Auxiliary lens normally serve to cover different zoom ranges.

for example here: http://www.2spi.com/catalog/ltmic/ZTX-3E-Microscope.shtml they say:

> Objective lens:
>   Zoom type objective lens that has a range of 1x to 4x comes "standard"
>   with the Series 3 "package". We also have available optional auxiliary
>   lens that literally "screw on" to the existing standard lens to make
>   possible the zoom function covering different zoom ranges. Such
>   auxiliary lenses are available as 0.5x, 0.75x, 1.5x, and 2x. The
>   installation of a 2x auxiliary lens permits a zoom function of 2x to
>   8x. A 0.5x auxiliary lens, reduces the zoom function range to 0.5x to
>   2x.

Comment: Do you think the claim of 90X zoom for the microscope described in my question is technically correct?

Comment: To answer that question I should trust the brand of the microscope. I sincerely don't know that brand. It all depends on the quality of the optics and the microscope design. 90x  zoom is technically possible and other brands do that.

Comment: Note that 90x "zoom" and 90x "magnification" are _not_ the same thing... 90x magnification is not a particularly challenging task for a microscope.